# Sensor that will produce a sinusoid phase locked to a high RPM Shaft

Tags: sensors

Is there a sensor that will produce a sinusoidal signal phase locked to a high RPM (7000 RPM) shaft? I am attempting to build a coaxial helicopter based on the architecture described in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6696528) which requires increasing and decreasing drive torque once per revolution, and I would like to do this modulation in hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a hall effect sensor would work for your application?
[(a)](http://reprap.org/wiki/MagServo)
[(b)](http://www.eeweb.com/company-blog/melexis/360-through-shaft-position-sensor-solution)
[(c)](http://archives.sensorsmag.com/articles/0306/20/main.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an AC motor connected to the shaft would act as a generator with the frequency of the sine wave matched to the rpm. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.